# Two dimensional array get [1] by [0]

Tags: java

What is the fastest one-line implementation to retrieve the value IDS[n][1] when provided with IDS[n][0] as an input using JDK-14.

I don't want to use for (not a one lined implementation). Ideally seeking how this would be done with more recently added java features or Arrays library maybe.

```
private static final int[][] IDS =
{
    { 20835, 21608 },
    { 21608, 21609 },
    { 20832, 21602 },
    { 21602, 21603 },
    { 20833, 21605 },
    { 21605, 21606 },
    { 21625, 21623 },
    { 21623, 21624 },
    { 20842, 21620 },
    { 21620, 21621 }
};
```

### Example 1:

Input: 20835
Output: 21608

Comment: Use Stream API `Arrays.stream(IDS).map(e -> e[1]).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: `IDS[0][1]`? not sure what exactly you are asking. What is the expected result?

Comment: Basically i want to search 20835 and get back the 21608 e.t.c

Comment: @fewkfwkfewfw might want to put that as an an example input/output in your question to make it clear.

Also if that is the requirement why not use a Map type? Is this just a trivia type question?

Answer (score 1):

Tested on an online compiler for JDK 11. The method GiveMeAName would be your implementation. This assumes that any passed parameter does indeed exist otherwise you will get an exception.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass {
    
    private static final int[][] IDS =
    {
        { 20835, 21608 },
        { 21608, 21609 },
        { 20832, 21602 },
        { 21602, 21603 },
        { 20833, 21605 },
        { 21605, 21606 },
        { 21625, 21623 },
        { 21623, 21624 },
        { 20842, 21620 },
        { 21620, 21621 }
    };
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(GiveMeAName(20835 ));
    }
    
    public static int GiveMeAName(int searchValue) {
        return Arrays.stream(IDS).filter(e -> e[0] == searchValue).map(e -> e[1]).findFirst().get();
    }
}
```